# Factory design pattern using __init_subclass__ python3

Tags: python-3.x, factory-pattern

I didn't find any info about the implementation of the factory design pattern using `__init_subclass__` to register the product and the class. What do you think about?
https://peps.python.org/pep-0487/

```
class Shape:
    product = None
    shapes_classes = {}

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        cls.shapes_classes[cls.product] = cls

    @classmethod
    def create_shape(cls, product, *args, **kwargs):
        return cls.shapes_classes[product](*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'I am {self.__class__.__name__} shape'

    def area(self):
        raise NotImplemented


class Triangle(Shape):
    product = 'triangle'

    def __init__(self, base, height):
        self.base = base
        self.height = height

    def area(self):
        return self.height * self.base / 2


class Square(Shape):
    product = 'square'

    def __init__(self, base, ):
        self.base = base

    def area(self):
        return self.base ** 2


#Usage:

Shape.shapes_classes

{'triangle': __main__.Triangle, 'square': __main__.Square}

triangle = Shape.create_shape(product='triangle',base=3,height=4)
square=Shape.create_shape(product='square',base=3)

print(triangle)
```

I am Triangle shape

`print(square`)

I am Square shape

```
triangle.area()
```

6.0

```
square.area()
```

9

Comment: For 'what do you think of this' type questions, you should probably generally post here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/
But even so, just wanted to say thanks for posting - I like this and it was a useful reference for a project I'm working on where I'm using a really similar design